# Unable to upload CSV file to database

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have an uploads page where a user can upload CSV files only. However, when i hit the upload button, nothing is uploaded to my database and no error messages are displayed. Only the go back button shows which means that my code must not be executing my code properly. How would i resolve this?

```
    CREATE TABLE `Jobs` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `order_ref` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `scott_packing` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `packing_price` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `courier_price` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `dispatch_type` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `tracking_number` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `job_status` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

**HTML:**

```
    <?
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(myusername))
{
    header("location:../index.php");
}
?>
<?
include("../template/header.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="toggle">
            <div class="header"><img style="float: right; padding: 10px;" src="../img/show.gif"><h4>Upload New File:</h4></div>  
    <form id="upload" action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="uploaded_file"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload file">
    </form>
    <!--<p>
        <a href="list_files.php" style="padding: 20px;">See all files</a>
    </p>-->
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**upload_file.php:**

```
    <?php


if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {
    if($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0) {

        $database = "spineless";

        $dblink = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "vario007")
           or die("Could not connect");

        $db = mysql_select_db($database)
        or die("Could not select database");

        if(mysql_errno()) {
            die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysql_error());
        }

        $file = $_FILES  ['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        $row = 1;
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",","'")) !== FALSE)
        {
            if($row == 1)
            {
                // skip the first row   
            }
            else
            {
                //csv format data like this 
                //$row[0] = date
                //$row[1] = order_ref
                //$row[2] = postcode
                //$row[3] = country
                //$row[4] = quantity
                //$row[5] = packing_price
                //$row[6] = dispatch_type

                $query = "
                INSERT INTO `Jobs` (
                `date`, `order_ref`, `postcode`, `country`, `quantity`, `packing_price`, `dispatch_type`, `created`
                )
                VALUES (
                '".$data[0]."', '".$data[1]."', '".$data[2]."', '".$data[3]."', '".$data[4]."', '".$data[5]."', '".$data[6]."', NOW()
                )";
                $result = mysql_query($query);


                 // Check if it was successfull
                if(!$result) {
                    echo 'Success! Your file was successfully added!';
                }
                else {
                    echo 'Error! Failed to insert the file';

                 }
            }
            $row++;
        }



    }
    else {
        echo 'An error accured while the file was being uploaded. '
           . 'Error code: '. intval($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error']);
    }

    // Close the mysql connection
    mysql_close();
}
else {
    echo 'Error! A file was not sent!';
}

// Echo a link back to the main page
echo '<p>Click <a href="joblist.php">here</a> to go back</p>';
?>
```

This is how the CSV looks like:
http://i754.photobucket.com/albums/xx182/rache_R/Screenshot2014-04-24at151348_zps807cedb0.png

Comment: I'd be much more concerned that the uploaded file doesn't follow the format you are expecting.

Comment: @TheBlueDog please can you elaborate?

Comment: Well, you are not checking the uploaded file format at all. What happens if you have text where you expect a number? What happens if there are 8 columns instead of 7? All of these things (and more!) can prevent the data being inserted into the DB. You are opening yourself up to a whole world of hurt here...

Comment: @TheBlueDog i understand what you are saying however, aside from setting the file format restrictions, my main concern at the moment is that i can't upload anything to my database

Comment: Ok, that's fine that you understand that :) I deal with CSV files daily, it's easy when they are generated by another application (until the vendor changes the format), but trying to insert data that came from a user is another matter.

Comment: Echo your query, and then paste the query in your databse.. See if thats works..

Comment: @user3519721: First things first, please post your DB structure, and the first few lines of your CSV file...

Comment: @TheBlueDog please see the above amendments

Comment: I don't see anything obvious, try commenting out `$result = mysql_query($query);` and adding `echo $query` - does it show anything?

Comment: @TheBlueDog nothing seems to be happening. My code just isn't executing any of the code within the if-statement. The only thing that is displayed is the final echo statement that says "click here to go back"

Comment: @user3519721: That would imply that `if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {` is false... What does you post HTML look like?

Comment: @TheBlueDog right ok. I have added my post HTML above

Comment: @user3519721: I dunno fella, that code works absolutely fine for me... It uploads a file then fails on the db part as I don't have one set up - I do at least get `could not connect`.

Answer (score 1):

So i have managed to solve my own question. After looking through my code i noticed that my code was fine up until the while loop. PHP was not properly recognizing the line endings when reading the file so enabling the `auto_detect_line_endings` run-time configuration helped solve my issue. NOTE that `auto_detect_line_endings` should be **set before** `fopen` and not after.

```
    <?php

if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {


    if($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0) {

        // Connect to database
        $database = "spineless";
        $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "vario007") or die("Could not connect");
        $db = mysql_select_db($database,$link) or die("Could not select database");

        // Upload file
        $file = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];
        ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true); // auto_detect_line_endings added here
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        $row = 1;
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",","'")) !== FALSE)
        {
            if($row == 1)
            {
                // skip the first row   
            }
            else
            {
                //csv format data like this 
                //$row[0] = date
                //$row[1] = order_ref
                //$row[2] = postcode
                //$row[3] = country
                //$row[4] = quantity
                //$row[5] = packing_price
                //$row[6] = dispatch_type

                $query = "
                INSERT INTO `Jobs` (
                `date`, `order_ref`, `postcode`, `country`, `quantity`, `packing_price`, `dispatch_type`, `created`
                )
                VALUES (
                '".$data[1]."', '".$data[2]."', '".$data[5]."', '".$data[6]."', '".$data[7]."', '".$data[9]."', '".$data[11]."', NOW()
                )";

                $result = mysql_query($query);




                 // Check if it was successfull
                if($result) {
                    echo 'Success! Your file was successfully added!';
                }
                else {
                    echo 'Error! Failed to insert the file';

                 }
            }
            $row++;
        }

    }
    else {
        echo 'An error accured while the file was being uploaded. ';
    }

    // Close the mysql connection
    mysql_close();
}
else {
    echo 'Error! A file was not sent!';
} 

// Echo a link back to the main page
echo '<p>Click <a href="joblist.php">here</a> to go back</p>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I set up a DB as per your info and created a CSV file using the data you supplied. The good news is that your code works absolutely fine (for me) as is, but for two small issues.

Your success message is the wrong way around, remove the `!`:

```
if($result){
echo 'Success! Your file was successfully added!';
}else{
echo 'Error! Failed to insert the file';
}
```

You are also trying to insert a date string `03/02/2014` into a DATE datatype. This won't work and you'll need to format this string accordingly. As a temporary measure I just changed the datatype in the DB to a VARCHAR(20).

With those two small things fixed:

[image]

Comment: i didn't realise i had the success message the wrong way round. Thanks for noticing that. Also, i have no idea why it doesn't work for me

Comment: @user3519721: The only other thing I just noticed is that in your HTML doc you are using the short PHP tags `<?`, I don't know whether this is causing your file upload problem or not. Just try `<?php` out of interest...

Comment: :( still doesn't work. It worked before when i first wrote the code but then it just stopped working which is very strange

Comment: @user3519721: I'll say! Sorry I can't offer any more help, but I just can't replicate your problem... What happens if you comment out `include("../template/header.php");`? Maybe something in there is somehow causing an issue.

Comment: i'll try fiddling with the code, thank you for your help though

Comment: @user3519721: You're welcome. Post an update when you find the problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?
session_start();
```

You cannot start a session **after** output has been sent to the browser, in this case, a few blankspaces.

Adjust this and better not use any sort of `short_open_tags`:

```
<?php
session_start();
```

Comment: I uploaded my new code above which already no longer uses the short opening tags